# I want to fetch the data from wordpress database

Tags: database, wordpress, fetch

Hi I have a question about wordpress. 
How does wordpress templates retrieve or fetch data from database? They must be having some query which I am not able to figure out. I want to create a new column to the database for ex, wp_data and fetch that column with the help of the function and display it. So I want to know how the template actually fetches data from database so that I can do the same. I tried contacting the support team of the template owners, but they replied saying they would provide the service only to the Pro version users. Please help me while I am stuck with this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch data from the database without using inbuilt functions go through with this link [interacting with the wordpress database](https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query)

Before you starts with wordpress read the document from its official site [wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) which will help you how wordpress works.